# Python GTK ScrolledWindow Height issue

Tags: python, gtk3, pygtk

I am using glade to generate the GTK application layout and using the python application for event handling. I have added a ScrolledWindow Component:

```
    <child>
      <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="GraphWindow">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="left_attach">0</property>
        <property name="top_attach">2</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
```

Now I trying to draw a chart using matplotlib in the above-given window.

```
class WeatherForecastApplicationBuilder(Gtk.Builder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Gtk.Builder.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.add_from_file("layout.glade")
        self.window = self.get_object("WeatherForecastWindow")
        self.graph_window = self.get_object("GraphWindow")

        self._get_widgets_()
        self.connect_signals(self)
        self.window.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def _draw_chart_(self):
        figure = Figure()
        subplot = figure.add_subplot(111)
        subplot.plot(
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
        )
        subplot.set(xlabel='Date', ylabel='Temp', title='Temprature Change')

        canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
        self.graph_window.add(canvas)
        self.window.show_all()
```

The issue is that the height of ScrolledWindow is fixed and not expanding. I want it to cover the whole window. The scrolled window is rendering like this:

[image: Scrolled Window]

How to expand the height of the ScrolledWindow Component so that the blank space at the bottom is covered.

[Link](https://file.io/ogteAs) to the complete glade layout file.

Comment: link doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting the following property to `true` in the ScrolledWindow object in `layout.glade` file.

`<property name="vexpand">True</property>`